# Derby Embedded Database Create Table Structure

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, derby

I am trying create a swing application with embedded database using netbeans IDE. First in the netbeans services tab i have created a database and connected using embedded driver. Then i have created all the tables and relationships there.

In the swing application i connected embedded database like this

```
private static String dbURL = "jdbc:derby:derbysample;create=true;user=root;password=root";

Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver").newInstance();
            //Get a connection
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL);
```

This creates the database and i could able to connect. But i doesn't create tables that i created. It's is standalone application. So for different machines it need to create database and tables. There are many solution?

- Create programatically tables [Add another java file to create tables and relationship]
- Get Schema of Database and build it.

My Question is "is there any easy way to add database structure to embedded database in standalone application?

**Abstract of question is:-**
Using a derby embedded database with large number of tables and relations. What is the best solution?

1. Create tables Programaticallly - How can i make it as runs only one
   time for each install
2. Use ant build tools to generate tables
3. Is there any other ways?

Comment: Have a look at Liquibase. It's a schema management tool that also has a Java API.

Answer (score -1):

Am assuming what you want is to create a database with specific tables during installation and use the same afterwards.

Derby is light weight database stored in single directory. Having said that creating tables is as simple as executing create table sql queries. Run this while you install.
`create=true;` in connection string means create an empty database if a matching one is not found (at the given path). This should be done only done at the time of installation.

You mentioned that you created the database with tables. While connecting from application you got an empty database.
Looks the application is not able to access the previously created database at given path (**derbysample** directory at working directory) and is creating a new database. Try giving the full path without create=true in connection  string

> private static String dbURL = "jdbc:derby:d:\\somepath\\derbysample;user=root;password=root";

This will force application to use an existing (previously created) database and throw an exception if the same is not found.